# Replying to a tweet using Twitterizer

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

My question is that I am trying to reply to a tweet. I have tweetId of the tweet. But cant reply it.

```
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
tokens.ConsumerKey = "xx";
tokens.ConsumerSecret = "xx";
tokens.AccessToken = "xx";
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "xx";

StatusUpdateOptions options = new StatusUpdateOptions()
{
    InReplyToStatusId=21,
};

TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, " hi",options);
```

This is my code but it is not working... Any suggestions... I guess Twitterizer has been changed

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be correct. The `Update` method returns an object that will give you details about the request you made to Twitter. Look at the values in that return value for the error message (if there is one).

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to reply a tweet

```
SendTweetOptions options = new SendTweetOptions();

            options.Status = "@twitterusername Reply to tweet ";
            options.InReplyToStatusId = 123456789;
            service.SendTweet(options);
```

It is important to remember that @twitterusername is mandatory to include because it's a wrapper . without that I don't think it will work .

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the TwitterStatus.InReplyToStatusId property before calling the Update method.

```
TwitterStatus.InReplyToStatusId = 21;
```

Comment: That is not correct for two reasons: InReplyToStatusId is a static/sealed and you pass optional parameters into methods using the Options classes.